# What is the best way to find all records of an e-mail for our company?

Tags: exchange

I need to find all records of e-mail conversations that occurred between a couple company employees and an external user (e-mail). Is it possible to do that with Exchange System Manager. Also, I have collected all of the employee's .OST files. Any help will be greatly  appreciated. Is there any software that you recommend that does this. I tried looking in the list of Mailboxes that we have through Exchange Manger but with no luck.

Comment: which version of exchange ? if you have the message tracking logs, you may find inside some useful information.

Comment: Is this an older version of exchange?  Ediscovery ha been part of the server for a while now.

Comment: To clarify: You need to find confirmation of these email "conversations" or you need to actually find the emails themselves so that they can be reviewed?

Answer (score 1):

Exchange System Manager sounds like Exchange 2003.

Message Tracking isn't going to help here. If you are doing a discovery process then you will need a third party tool to scan the database. OST files aren't going to be much help.

Confirming the version of Exchange has to be the first thing you need to do.

Oh and third party software isn't going to be very cheap either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the version of your Exchange is 2003 since you did mention Exchange System Manager. There isn't much options available to you. Third-party options for harvesting that data could be quite expensive. If you are doing a search of a few users, you might be better off exporting their entire mailbox, and perform a search via Outlook within the PST/Export.

If you have to search through a larger number of users, good case scenario if you have specifics to the item in question (eg. subject), you can consider using EXMERGE. It is used to extract mailboxes into PST files. Its quite old and not very granular, but you can use the limited option to extract based on date, subject and/or name of the attachments.
This utility works with Exchange 2003

XADM: Some Questions and Answers About the Exmerge Utility 
(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/265441)

How do I use EXMERGE to delete specific messages from Exchange 2000/2003 mailboxes?
(https://www.petri.com/delete_messages_from_mailboxes_by_using_exmerge)

View the tool's screenshot from petri to see if these options are sufficient to narrow on the items in question. Good luck!